# Optimal structure between multiple forms and multiple classes (C# Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I am quite new to C#. After searching, I did not find related questions on this problem. I want to think this problem as an architecture view. I will try to make the explanation clear :P.

For example, I have two FORMs(main FORM, camera setting FORM) and one class(class Camera). 
When the application starts, main FORM will show up first.

Main FORM needs to communicate with camera.
The setting FORM is generated by clicking a button on main form.
Setting FORM needs to communicate with camera as well.

My question is, for setting FORM to communicate with camera, is it necessary to pass the return value first to main FORM? And then main FORM will communicate with the camera?

If so, it will be very complicated when there are several forms and several classes.
If not, could I have a broad picture on what should be done? Such as delegate or threads or what?

Comment: Forms are a visual addon... You need to think in terms of the behaviour of the item doing the work (e.g. the class Camera). The Camera class will expose events that the forms listen for (e.g. onPictureTaken) and methods they can call (e.g. takePicture()). The forms will be handed a reference to a single camera object when created and can add their own event handlers to it at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms are meant as mere shells that direct input and output between the user and classes containing business logic.

For example "take picture" is business logic that would reside in the Camera class:

```
class Camera
{
    public Picture TakePicture()
    {
        return _cameraAPI.TakePicture();
    }
}
```

Upon a "take picture" button click on the main form, you call `camera.TakePicture()`.

> My question is, for setting form to communicate with camera, is it necessary to pass the return value first to main form? And then main formwill communicate with the camera?

You can pass an instance of the Camera class to each form, so they can operate independently of each other. You can do this through constructor injection, where you adapt each form with a new constructor that accepts a `Camera` instance, then you keep a local reference to it:

```
class MainForm
{
    private Camera _camera;

    public MainForm(Camera camera)
        : this()
    {
        _camera = camera;
    }
}
```

Then in your main method, where you show the main form:

```
var camera = new Camera();
var mainForm = new MainForm(camera);

Application.Run(mainForm);
```

Now when you want to show the settings form from the main form, repeat:

```
public void Settings_Click()
{
    // Pass camera reference
    var settingsForm = new SettingsForm(_camera);

    settingsForm.ShowDialog();
}
```